# How to check "remote area" for an order in FedEx API | Laravel | PHP

Tags: php, laravel, fedex

I am using "Arkitecht/fedex-laravel" package in Laravel. I have implemented create the shipment and many more. Now my requirement is to check the remote area for an order. Which FedEx API is used to get my desired result. I do not find anything on FedEx documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get Surcharges variable in your response.

"Description": **"Out of delivery area"** => This line denotes Remote Area.

```
"Surcharges": [
{
    "SurchargeType": 50,
    "SurchargeTypeSpecified": true,
    "LevelSpecified": false,
    "Description": "Out of delivery area",
    "Amount": {
        "Currency": "SID",
        "Amount": 32.3
    }
},
```